# How to make this kind of border css?

Tags: css

How did this designer (Mason Yarnell) designed this border separating the 3 menu bar sections?

From what I see, its more than a solid border.

https://dribbble.com/shots/1315388-Dashboard-Web-App-UI-Job-Summary/attachments/184703

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: show your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: A simple border-top: 3px solid rgb(53, 53, 53)
but I think he might be using a box and place a shadow around it.

Comment: Problem solved! It's actually simple.
  border-top: 3px solid #2b3544;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #303a4a;
By making the top border thicker and more dense than the bottom border, this gives a "box separation" effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this css to make this border,

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/mvt2r6zw/)***

Css:-

```
.main{height: 20px;width: 400px;margin: 100px auto;}
.main ul li{padding:10px;border-top:1px solid #2b3544;border-bottom:1px solid #303a4a;list-style: none;min-height: 50px;position: relative;}
.main ul li:after{border-bottom: 1px solid #293241;content: '';width: 100%;height: 1px;position: absolute;left:0px;top:-4px;}
.main ul li:before{border-bottom: 1px solid #3d495d;content: '';width: 100%;height: 1px;position: absolute;left:0px;top:-1px;}
.main ul li:first-child{border-top:none;}
.main ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none;}
.main ul li:first-child:after ,.main ul li:first-child:before{display: none;}
```